# Unable to use catkin in ROS2 humble with Ubuntu 22.04

Tags: apt, software-installation, 22.04, workspaces, ros

I have installed ROS2 by following the guide in [this document](https://docs.ros.org/en/humble/Installation/Ubuntu-Install-Debians.html)
but when I tried to install catkin by the following command:

```
$ mkdir -p ~/catkin_ws/src
$ cd ~/catkin_ws/src
$ catkin_init_workspace
```

It gives me this error

```
Command 'catkin_init_workspace' not found
```

I typed the command:

```
$ sudo apt install catkin
```

It gives me this kind of error :

```
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 python3-catkin-pkg : Conflicts: catkin but 0.8.10-7 is to be installed
 python3-catkin-pkg-modules : Conflicts: catkin but 0.8.10-7 is to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

Comment: Hi and welcome to AskUbuntu: I tried to beautify our questions. But there seams to be some logical error in our question - The installation of catkin failed - not the usage.

Comment: The exact same question was asked [here](https://askubuntu.com/q/1413097/134479).